# Powershell: Using powershell commands inside html formatting

Tags: html, powershell, formatting

I'm doing a daily check of Hyper-V VM's and i get the output as required in HTML format.
However, there is always room for improvement in html formatting and i need assistance with the following problem.

I have the following Array

```
$outputArray = @()
foreach($VM in $VMS) { 
      $VMsRAM = [math]::round($VM.Memoryassigned/1GB)
      $VMsCPU = $VM.processorCount
      $VMsState = $VM.State
      $VMsStatus = $VM.Status
      $VMsUptime = $VM.Uptime
      $VMsAutomaticstartaction = $VM.Automaticstartaction
      $VMsIntegrationServicesVersion = $VM.IntegrationServicesVersion
      $VMsReplicationState = $VM.ReplicationState
      $VHDsGB = @{ label="File_Size"; Expression={[math]::round($_.FileSize/1GB)}}
      $VHDs = Get-VHD -ComputerName $VM.ComputerName -VMId $VM.Id | Select Path, VHDType, VHDFormat, $VHDsGB

      $output = new-object psobject
      $output | add-member noteproperty "VM Name" $VM.Name
      $output | add-member noteproperty "RAM(GB)" $VMsRAM
      $output | add-member noteproperty "vCPU" $VMsCPU
      $output | add-member noteproperty "State" $VMsState
      $output | add-member noteproperty "Status" $VMsStatus
      $output | add-member noteproperty "Uptime" $VMsUptime
      $output | add-member noteproperty "Start Action" $VMsAutomaticstartaction
      $output | add-member noteproperty "Integration Tools" $VMsIntegrationServicesVersion
      $output | add-member noteproperty "Replication State" $VMsReplicationState
      $output | add-member noteproperty "VHD Path" $VHDs.Path
      $output | add-member noteproperty "Size GB" $VHDs.File_Size
      $output | add-member noteproperty "VHD Type" $VHDs.vhdtype
      $output | add-member noteproperty "VHD Format" $VHDs.vhdformat
      $outputArray += $output
 }
```

Next, I throw the output using html formatting

```
#Export contents to htm
if($outputArray -ne $null) {
    $HTML5 = '<style type="text/css">
    #Header{font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;}
    #Header td, #Header th {font-size:14px;border:1px solid #98bf21;padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;}
    #Header th {font-size:14px;text-align:left;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#A7C942;color:#fff;}
    #Header tr.alt td {color:#000;background-color:#EAF2D3;}
    </Style>'
    $HTML5 += "<font face=verdana size=4 color=#23B108><b><CENTER>VMGuest Tech Spec's</CENTER></b></font>"
    $HTML5 += "<HTML><BODY><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% id=Header>
        <TR>
            <TH><B>VM Name</B></TH>
            <TH><B>RAM(GB)</B></TD>
            <TH><B>vCPU</B></TD>
            <TH><B>State</B></TD>
            <TH><B>Uptime</B></TD>
            <TH><B>Integration Tools</B></TD>
            <TH><B>Replication State</B></TD>
            <TH><B>VHD Path</B></TD>
            <TH><B>Size GB</B></TD>
            <TH><B>VHD Type</B></TD>
            <TH><B>VHD Format</B></TD>
        </TR>"

Foreach($Entry in $outputArray){
    $HTML5 += "<TR>
            <TD>$($Entry.'VM Name')</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.'RAM(GB)')</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.vCPU)</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.State)</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.Uptime)</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.'Integration Tools')</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.'Replication State')</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.'VHD Path')<BR></TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.'Size GB')</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.'VHD Type')</TD>
            <TD>$($Entry.'VHD Format')</TD>

        </TR>"

}
```

The above code works fine. However, "$($Entry.'VHD Path')
" results in multiple path's as there are multiple virtual disk's & this clutter;s my report. 
Now, My question is how do i format each output into a separate line inside the table.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `$Entry.'VHD Path'` is an array? (or possibly just a comma-separated string...?)

Comment: Yes, Its part of the array...Within the array i'm giving labels for each value that im fetching.

The following gathers all the path info with other information.
$VHDs = Get-VHD -ComputerName $VM.ComputerName -VMId $VM.Id | Select Path, VHDType, VHDFormat, $VHDsGB 

Only the path element $VHDs.Path is now been given a Label
$output | add-member noteproperty "VHD Path" $VHDs.Path

Finally in the HTML formatted output im using the Label name
 <TD>$($Entry.'VHD Path')<BR></TD>

Answer (score 1):

You can use $OFS variable (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx). It specifies the character that separates the elements of an array when the array is converted to a string.

For example :

```
$OFS = "`n"
$array = Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE
Write-Host "$array"
```

This will output array elements separated by NewLine character instead of whitespace.

In your case you will need to use `$OFS = "<br />"`

Comment: Perfect..Works like a charm.
Thank you Levgen :)